# Unable to make raspberry pi publicly accessible

Tags: dhcp, dns, apache-httpd

This is my first time playing with the DNS and the internet. I want to make my RasPi publicly accessible. I followed the below steps:

1. Set up the apache2 server, and access it locally from home network.
2. Then, I edited the dhcpcd.conf file and made the private IP static. I set the below information.

> `static ip_address = desired static IP for the RasPi`
> `static routers = My routers IP address. Fetched from Network and Sharing center > Wifi > Details > IPv4 Default Gateway`
> `static domain_name_servers = got this from resolv.conf [8.8.8.8]`

---

> The actual contents of the file are:
> `interface wlan0`
> `static ip_address=192.168.1.101/24`
> `static routers=192.168.1.1`
> `static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8`

3. I even confirmed from my ISP if I can access port 80 and port forwarding, and if it is not blocked. He confirmed it isn't.
4. I added the IP address of pi in the routers port forwarding section (for HTTP and DNS)
5. Additionally I set up a DNS service from NO-IP and added DUC in raspi device so that it can trace the dynamic public IP.

Where did I went wrong ? I followed exactly from : https://www.makeuseof.com/raspberry-pi-set-static-ip/

---

I attempted to access the newly created hostname domain from NOIP with my LTE cellular network, but it says

> The connection has timed out
>
> The server at *public IP* is taking too long to respond.

Any help is appreciated :-)

[image: Router port forwarding settings]

**UPDATE: The ISP confirmed that they provide CGNAT IPv4 technology, and in order to obtain a static IP, the consumer needs to pay for that.**

Comment: shoudln't `ip_address = desired static IP for the RasPi` be `static ip_address = desired static IP for the RasPi`

Comment: can you show what you **actually** did in `dhcpcd.conf` - it's not like showing private ip's is at all dangerous - mines 192.168.1.20 - does that mean 1337 h4x0r5 are gonna pwn me now that they know that? (no

Comment: @Bravo I forgot to add the correct value. It was indeed static ip_address. The intention behind not adding the IP addresses, was not the security risk. Stating the IP addresses, wouldn't have clarified my intention of adding specific IPs to the particular values. I have now edited the question and added the actual content of dhcpcd.conf

Comment: I wanted to see if you did it correctly - have you confirmed that the DDNS ip address is correct?

Comment: @Bravo, Yes. I have installed a DUC in raspberry pi. Per it's description it continually updates the dynamic IP. I even reconfirmed using "what's my IP". But to no avail.

Comment: Sure you forwarded port 80 on the router? Sometimes it can take a minute to update. Also can check logs on the router and for your apache server and see if you see anything useful in there.

Comment: @ChadG. I have added the router port forwarding setting in the question. I checked in Syslog, found nothing much relevant to port 80.

Comment: Are you sure your attempting port 80 and not 443 (ssl) When you are browsing to the webpage?

Comment: Yes, I am using port 80 while entering the webpage

Comment: @DaSnipeKid "I checked in Syslog, found nothing much relevant to port 80" - you should have checked the apache logs (in `/var/log/apache2/`), and they should show successful access from `192.168.1.xxx`, corresponding to your successful tests in step 1.

Comment: Just saw your update about the static public IP being a paid option. Note that services like NO-IP offer an API to update the IP address without going through their web page, and some ISPs support this API. In that case you can provide your NO-IP login and password to the ISP and they can do the update every time your public IP changes. You don't need a static IP then. Though they are unlikely to do this if they want you to pay for a static IP :(

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure your apache2 setup really works. Assuming you have a laptop connected to the same router as the Pi, open a browser and type in `http://192.168.1.101:80/`. Your Pi webpage should show up.

If the webserver works, learn your public IPv4 address. Don't trust your provider or your router, and don't use DNS, visit `https://whatismyipaddress.com/` or ask Google. Let's assume you get `98.76.54.32`.

Now, type in your browser `http://98.76.54.32:80/` and see what happens. If your Pi webpage shows up, proceed further. Otherwise, see why port forwarding is not working. Try rebooting your router and see if the configuration you made actually persists. If there's still nothing, try to check for open ports using online services (e.g. `https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/`) or a torrent client if you happen to use one.

There is also the option to use UPnP (if your router has it enabled) - that's what torrent client do internally, but you can install the `miniupnpc` package and do it for your web server as well:

```
upnpc -a 192.168.1.101 80 80 TCP
```

Or, if you decide not to use a static IP address:

```
upnpc -a $(ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1) 80 80 TCP
```

If port forwarding works, go ahead with your DNS name setup. First off, wait a while: DNS is by no means fast. It may take a few hours for your NO-IP name to become public. Check that you have the exact `98.76.54.32` IP  listed on your NO-IP account. Note that many providers don't have enough static public IPs for all customers, so your IP could change from time to time. It's usually possible to set up your router in a way that IP updates are automatically sent to NO-IP. Look for a config page in your router that looks like this:

[image]

Additionally, many providers offer you a domain name of their own, that usually works fine - something like `dasnipekid.provider.com`. Try using this one if you can't get NO-IP to work.

Comment: `http://192.168.1.101:80/` works. However, I tried to access the public IP (I tried earlier as well), it shows connection has timed out. However, there's a catch. I recently learned from a different forum, that the public IP ( fetched from https://whatismyipaddress.com/ )and the WAN IP shown in router homepage do not match. May be that's the reason why this isn't working.

Comment: Sure, you need the public IP. WAN IP is likely still local (does it start with 10? then it certainly is), or it may not be routable for other reasons. Did the public IP work?

Comment: It starts with 100.xx.xxx.xxx. The public IP didn't worked.

Comment: Since port 22 is also forwarded can you try ssh to your public ip?

Comment: @Paul Sure, it's worth a try, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: @DaSnipeKid Try to check for open ports on your IP address using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: Just wondered if the 2 IP addresses @DaSnipeKid sees means there's a proxy server in between, though his ISP seems to indicate not. Also are you running any firewalls on the Pi like ufw?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev, it says the port 80 is closed.

Comment: @Paul, the ufw has ports 22 and 80 opened and listening. And I guess, the ufw isn't installed by default on Raspberry OS. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DaSnipeKid yeah ufw was never installed by default on any images I did. It's probably no issue but just to rule it out maybe try disabling ufw and do another port scan. I've been tripped up by firewalls many times...

Comment: @DaSnipeKid Does your router have UPnP enabled? If so, I would try to install `miniupnpc` package and run something like `upnpc -a $(ifconfig wlan0 | grep 'inet addr' | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1) 80 80 TCP`. If the port is still closed, I'd turn to your ISP for support, perhaps they lied to your the first time when they said the port was open.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev the UPnP is indeed enabled, however after running the script it says, `Found a (not connected?) IGD : http://192.168.1.1:1980/control?WANIPConnection No valid UPNP Internet Gateway Device found.`. I think the ISP was unaware (probably the customer care have predefined FAQs answers and she could have answered abruptly) of the opened port 80.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have an internal IP conflict.  Usually home routers reserve everything over 192.168.1.100 for DHCP.  If 2 devices share the same IP, you can't guarantee which device receives the incoming http request.  Given that you used a static 101, one of the first reserved DHCP IPs, that greatly increases the risk.  Try a static IP between 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.99

Comment: This is not at all universal, e.g. my router's DHCP range is between 10 and 99, and IPs below 10 are used for its internal functions like DLNA. Also note that the IP conflict would have prevented HTTP access to 192.168.1.101, which the OP claims is working.

Comment: If the Pi were wired to a switch, and the device checking it locally was on the same switch, and the conflicting IP was further upstream on the wifi router, it could behave as described.  However, it looks like they are connecting the Pi via Wifi so this probably isn't the cause.  Either way I'd verify the IP is outside the DHCP range.

Comment: @rtaft, answer to your query:  `IP pool start address - 192.168.1.100` & `IP pool end address - 192.168.1.199`. This is the DHCP range.

Comment: I agree with @DmitryGrigoryev. I am able to access the web page on home network, and I changed the static IP in dhcpcd.conf file to 192.168.1.97. Nevertheless, I was able to access the web page on my home network (LAN), but was unable to access the same through public IP.